# Is there any button click event in Sitecore Tracker in version 9.1

Tags: sitecore, event-tracking, sitecore-mvc

I am looking for a personalization event that have to occur when a click event takes place.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not and you have to track your button click event on the server side in Sitecore.

Add an `onclick()` JavaScript event to your button to make the server call and pass details about the clicked button. Then register the click event as a **Goal** on the server side.

You can create a Goal and then trigger it as a pre-built Sitecore event using
the `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterGoal()` method to register your Goal against the current page as follows:

```
var goalId = "{Your Goal ID}"; // ID of your goal
var goalDefinition = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.Goals[goalId];
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterGoal(goalDefinition);
```

Read more about the pre-built events in Sitecore [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/triggering-built-in-events.html).